# Groovy closure returns null

Tags: regex, groovy, nullpointerexception

I wanted to understand this piece of code which returns a null value when I expect a regular expression result.

```
String pattern = ent.getKey()
Closure function = ent.getValue()
String postContent = post.content.toString()
String match = function(postContent =~ pattern)?.toLowerCase()
```

**Match** returns a null object. Even though I use a

```
if (postContent =~ pattern)
```

The above line too returns a null value. My pattern is

```
pattern = "(?:Hi|Hey|Greetings|Afternoon|Morning|Hello|Dear)[,;\s]\s*(\w+)[\.!,?]?\s+(?!here|from\s+\w+\s+here).+"

postContent = "Hi there, something something something...."
```

I would appreciate help in understanding the difference and what I could go about doing.

Comment: Hey there. First of all, ```=~``` returns ```Matcher``` object. Is it really the input your ```function()``` is accepting, not the ```Boolean```? Just to be clear. Also, if ```pattern``` and ```postContent``` are as you provided - ```postContent =~ pattern``` actually returns ```Matcher``` object, although ```pattern``` should be slashy string (surrounded with ```/```), not the regular one.

Comment: Hi @Mugi4ok, `function()`'s arguments are indeed `post.content =~ pattern`. This is legacy code and I was trying to use a matcher object ` Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternt).matcher(postContent);` and maybe using a group(). I am trying to pattern match the start of a string with a pattern as _(?:Hi|Hey|Greetings|Afternoon|Morning|Hello|Dear)[,;\s]\s*(\w+)[\.!,?]?\s+(?!here|from\s+\w+\s+here).+_                                                      Would you happen to have any thoughts ?